# when is it safe to release an NSThread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

Below is the runloop for my secondary NSThread* processThread

To close the thread I call

```
//cancel secondary thread
[processThread cancel]
//signal condition
[processCondition broadcast];
```

**Is it then safe to then call:**

```
[processCondition release];
[processThread release];
```

**or do i need to be sure that the thread has finished?**


Perhaps like this?

```
NSTimeInterval timeout = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + (1.0/15.0);

while ([processThread isExecuting] && [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] < timeout)
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0/1000.0 ];
}

[processCondition release];
[processThread release];
```

*detailed code and explanation:*

```
- (void)processLoop
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * outerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [processCondition lock];

    //outer loop    
    //this loop runs until my application exits
    while (![[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled])    
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *middlePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc];
        if(processGo)
        {
            //inner loop
            //this loop runs typically for a few seconds
            while (processGo && ![[NSThread currentThread] isCancelled]) 
            {
                NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]; init];
                //within inner loop
                //this takes a fraction of a second
                [self doSomething];
                [innerPool release];
            }
            [self tidyThingsUp];

        }
        else
        {
            [processCondition wait];
        } 
        [middlePool release];
    }
    [processCondition unlock];      
    [outerPool release];
}
```

the combination of:

- an inner while loop
- NSCondition *processCondition
- toggling `processGo` between `YES` and `NO`

allows me to stop and start the inner while loop without cancelling the thread.

```
if (processGo == YES)
```

execution enters the inner while loop.

When the main thread sets

```
processGo = NO
```

execution leaves the inner while loop and tidys up 
on the next pass of the outer loop, execution hits

```
[processCondition wait]
```

and waits

if the the main thread resets

```
processGo == YES
```

and calls

```
[processCondition wait]
```

execution re-enters the inner loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to call release against an NSThread if you are done with it. In non-GC Objective C code the idiom is that once you are done accessing an object you may release it. If anything else needs that object, including the object itself it their job to have a retain against it. In general if an object cannot be safely disposed at arbitrary times it will retain itself while it is in an unsafe state, and release itself when it can be safely disposed of.

This is how things like NSThread and NSURLConnection work (NSURLConnection actually retains its delegate and does a lot of fancy stuff to cope with the retain loop that occurs.

Comment: Just because you are "done with it" doesn't mean the thread is altogether finished executing. Calling `cancel` on a thread doesn't guarantee you can release it right away.

Comment: Yes, but while it is executing it retains itself.

Comment: @Louis: You're correct - sorry, didn't quite read the docs closely enough. Disregard my last comment.

Comment: No problem, threading and retain semantics are tricky things. There also used to be some really nasty bugs and gotchas that made everything a lot more complicated than the docs would imply.