# "Just Leaking" when Threading from a Callback Function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I am new to iphone programming. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

All is ok when I start a new NSThread from within an obj-c method or a C function like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(hello) toTarget:thisSelf withObject:nil];
```

(thisSelf=self, i use this to be able to start the thread from within a C function)

However, if I have a C callback function that is called from a separate C thread starting this NSThread instead (in the exact same way), I get "NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking"

Why the leak? I cannot figure out how to avoid this, since creating an NSAutoreleasePool in method "hello" does not seem to solve this.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// code of method "hello" here  
[pool release];
```

Any insights/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `+detachNewThreadSelector:...` creates an autoreleased NSThread object, so your separate C thread that sends that message needs an autorelease pool too.  You can avoid this by explicitly creating the NSThread object:

```
NSThread* newThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget: thisSelf 
                                              selector: @selector(hello) 
                                                object: nil];
[newThread start];
[newThread release];  // this might not be OK.  You might need to wait until the thread is finished
```

although, the internals of the init method might need an autorelease pool too in which case, you'll just have to create one.

If you are creating your C thread using posix threads, you have a problem in that you need to [notify the Cocoa framework that the application is now multithreaded](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-125024-BAJGFJED) when you start your first Posix thread.

Comment: Relevant to the question of releasing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151637/when-is-it-safe-to-release-an-nsthread

Answer (score 0):

your implementation of hello lloks fine.

next:

break on whatever symbol that is (NSAutoreleaseNoPool?) and tell me: which thread is this called from?

i suspect you may not have an autorelease pool set up in the thread which you create the secondary thread in.

if not, and it's the *new* thread, then you're not creating the autorelease pool early enough.

(more code would help if that doesn't solve it for you)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this way:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(hello) toTarget:thisSelf withObject:nil];
[pool drain];
```